# Automatically port conversion elements of C code to C++

Tags: c++, c, casting

Is there some tool that can automatically convert the following c style code

```
A *a = b;
```

to

```
A *a = (A*)b;
```

Thanks,
James

Comment: While you're converting C-style code to C++, you might as well use C++ style casts as well: A a* = static_cast<A*>(b);

Comment: Almost a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272570/how-to-find-and-replace-all-old-c-style-data-type-casts-in-my-c-source-code

Comment: I think that question is asking about if it's possible to replace (A*) with static_cast<A*>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is to eliminate compiler errors, I would probably write one myself. Run the compiler on the source, and redirect error messages to a file. Filter out the errors where it complains about the type. For example, in gcc, they will look like this:

```
a.cc:3: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
```

This gives you all you need: file and line number, as well as the type you need to cast to (i.e. `int*`). Find a likely place in the line to insert the cast (i.e. after the = character, or after the return statement), and try again. Keep track of the lines that you already edited, and skip them for human intervention.

Comment: Yea that's a good suggestion. I'm looking for some preexisting tool at the moment, though, before I go and roll my own.