# Is there a way of disabling the old c style casts in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find (and replace) all old C-style data type casts in my C++ source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272570/how-to-find-and-replace-all-old-c-style-data-type-casts-in-my-c-source-code)

I'm currently refactoring some old code and the project I am working on has a policy of only using the new c++ style casts. I'm trying to make sure that I don't miss any but currently the approach I'm taking is quite crude so I'm wondering if there is any way of making the old c style casts not compile in a c++ project? (or at least give a compiler warning if this is not possible)

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272570/how-to-find-and-replace-all-old-c-style-data-type-casts-in-my-c-source-code] for a solution with GCC.

Comment: @hammar, is there a way to do this with other non-gcc compilers?

Comment: @shuttle87: Things like these are very compiler-specific. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: It's a different question than the one linked as a duplicate.  This question asks how to _disable_ the old-style C casts, whereas the linked question asks how to _find and replace_ them.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you use GCC, add `-Wold-style-cast` to the command line. That gives warnings, not errors, but you can always add `-Werror`, which turns warnings (*all* warnings) into errors.

As for other compilers, it seems no other compiler has such a warning option.

But that doesn't really matter: GCC is Free Software, and available on practically anything that can distinguish between zeros and ones. Just install it alongside your main compiler on your workstation, or into your continuous integration system, and use it for this task only. You will find that having two C++ compilers at hand is very convenient in general.

If installing GCC really isn't an option for you, you might want to take a peek at [How to find (and replace) all old C-style data type casts in my C++ source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272570/how-to-find-and-replace-all-old-c-style-data-type-casts-in-my-c-source-code), where *some* alternatives are discussed.

Comment: Amazing, thankyou! But what about other compilers?

Comment: @huttle87: see the thread hammar linked which seems to have established that GCC is the only compiler with such an option. Which isn't much of a problem, because gcc is available nearly everywhere, you just need to install it alongside your main compiler (which is something you should do anyway, testing with two compilers, I mean :)

Comment: @mmutz: funny, I see that clang has implemented the parsing of this flag, however it's a stub and not mapped to anything susbtantial :)

Comment: "Just install it alongside your main compiler on your workstation, or into your continuous integration system, and use it for this task only" - certainly worth a try, but not a complete solution. It only helps if the code is sufficiently portable to compile on GCC. Making the code compile on mingw32 isn't a bad exercise, but even then it won't find C-style casts in code inside `#ifdef MSC_VER`  or whatever.

Comment: @Matthieu: doesn't Clang make some effort to be option-compatible with GCC, to make it easier to switch between them? Could be they haven't got round to implementing it, or could just be a bodge so that makefiles etc work.

Comment: I personally like using gcc but as is often the case with these things convincing other people can be tricky. I guess using GCC just for this task alone seems acceptable as main change is just to this element of the code alone.

Comment: @Steve: yes they do, for option parsing, code parsing and code generation (though they are not bug compatible), and I guess that's why they have a number of such "options".

Comment: Regarding `-Werror` applying to all warnings: you can write `-Werror=old-style-cast` to apply it selectively instead.

Comment: Clang now supports `-Wold-style-cast` properly, not sure about other C compilers.  It's been long enough they might.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [`this Perl script`](http://www.abisource.com/mailinglists/abiword-dev/2003/May/0198.html).  Except for unusual conditions like
    (void**)&b.ComInterfaceCall
it just appears to work.