# Removing C-style casts in C++ code under Android

Tags: c++, android, c, casting, android-ndk

I saw this post on SO: [Is there a way of disabling the old c style casts in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922992/is-there-a-way-of-disabling-the-old-c-style-casts-in-c), and was excited to apply `-Wold-style-cast` to my Android C++ code.  I quickly ran into the following casts in `stdio.h`:

```
static __inline int __sputc(int _c, FILE *_p) {
    if (--_p->_w >= 0 || (_p->_w >= _p->_lbfsize && (char)_c != '\n'))
        return (*_p->_p++ = _c);
    else
        return (__swbuf(_c, _p));
}
```

The file `stdio.h` was included through a series of other includes starting from `ostream`.  Should C++ library headers include C headers that do C style casts?  Has anyone tried disabling C style casts under Android NDK?

Comment: The C++ standard _includes_ the C library (such as `<cstring>` and `<cstdlib>`). Surely an implementation should be allowed to include the C library headers, or would you prefer a complete rewrite?

Comment: OK, updated the question to be more to the point.  I was hoping C++ library headers didn't cause C style casts to be brought in.

Comment: @suravi: What's your beef with C-style casts? They're used correctly and they don't get in your way, and they create identical code compared to `static_cast`, so why not just live and let live?

Comment: Wow, if that warning existed in Visual Studio, the compilation output would explode, as the implementation uses nothing *but* C-style casts...

Comment: @Kerrek SB, the header C style casts do get in my way when I turn on the compiler warning to catch C casts in my own code.  Other than that, I have no problem with them since I'm sure they're safe.  I'll try @Peter's suggestion below.

Comment: @suravi: Fair enough. I was trying to create that situation, though, but my GCC4.6 never warns me about old style casts in its C library... how exactly can I cause this problem?

Comment: @suravi: According to the manual, "Warnings from system headers are normally suppressed". So I still wonder how C-style casts in the library could be getting in your way.

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.5.2, and if I use -Wold-style-cast on my Android code, I get over 70,000 warnings.  I tried a similar, but very small test on Linux code, and it doesn't produce any warnings.  Haven't looked into why though.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: The problem with C casts is not that when correctly used they are equivalent to `static_cast`, but that it is simple to make mistakes and have it behave like `reinterpret_cast` rather than complain...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid for a C++ standard library header to include C headers.

If you want to get around this (without modifying the standard library code), you can disable the warnings before including the header then re-enable them using [GCC Diagnostic Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wold-style-cast"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// etc.
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The `push` and `pop` are there so that you can maintain the state of the diagnostics before and after the `#pragmas`.

Of course, you'll need to do this everywhere that you include the standard headers. If you have a lot of places that include them then it might be best to "refactor" your includes so that all your headers include one single header, which in turn includes the standard headers with the `diagnostic` wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, obviously C++ headers may include C headers. And the standard doesn't prohibit any header to perform a C-style cast. No, I haven't tried that feature. Personally I avoid using C-Style casts without aid of the compiler.

Comment: Just edited my question to say "should C++ **library** headers include C headers".

Comment: @suravi: Some c++ standard library headers, such as `<cstdlib>`, `<ctime>` etc. do include C headers, such as `<stdlib.h>` and `<time.h>`, and others, too, may include them, if necessary. No clause in the standard prohibits that